# Measure theory problem from Stein real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on the sphere $S^{d-1} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d:|x|=1\}$ which is rotation-invariant in the sense that $\mu(r(E)) = \mu(E),$ for every rotation $r$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and each Borel subset $E$ of $S^{d-1}.$ If $\mu(S^{d-1}) < 
\infty,$ then $\mu$ is a constant multiple of measure $\sigma$ arising in the polar coordinate integration formula.

There is a hint in this problem:
Show that $\int_{S^{d-1}} Y_{k}(x) d \mu(x) = 0$ for every surface spherical harmonic of degree $k \ge 1.$ This would imply that there is a constant $c$ such that
$$\int_{S^{d-1}}fd\mu = c\int_{S^{d-1}}fd\sigma$$ for every continuous functions $f$ on $S^{d-1}.$

I am thinking to show the hint we need to use stieltjes integral properties and Ergodic theorems but not having much luck so far.

Comment: How do you define $r(E)$? Can you explain how the hint allows you to assert the desired equality? Finally, it is not too difficult to show there is a unique rotation-invariant measure on the $d-1$ sphere such that $\sigma(S^{d-1}) = 1$; normalising $\mu(\cdot)/\mu(S^{n-1})$ would yield your result. Would you like to see the argument?

Edit:  I take rotation-invariant to mean $\mu(A) = \mu(RA)$ for every $R \in SO(d,\mathbb{R})$, $RA = \{Rx : x \in A\}$.

Comment: It seems easier to do this directly, as suggested by snarski. For example, if you have Lebesgue's differentiation theorem available, you can argue as follows: write $d\mu = f\, d\sigma + d\nu$, with $\nu$ singular wrt $\sigma$. Then $\nu$ is supported by the set where $d\mu/d\sigma=\infty$, which cannot have positive $\mu$ measure by rotational invariance. So $\nu=0$. Then rotational invariance also shows that $f=c$.